# How to call POST request from one controller to another controller

Tags: spring-mvc

First I am calling GET request from browser, then within controller of this GET request  I would like to call POST request to other controller.

Here is the code that I am using:-

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/get.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMethodCall(ModelMap modelMap){

        return "forward:/post.do";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/post.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postMethodCall(ModelMap modelMap){

        return "success";
    }

}
```

But it is showing below error:-

```
Jan 25, 2015 12:37:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

It seems `forward` is supported for GET here. Please help.

Comment: Just invoke `postMethodCall` from within `getMethodCall`, as with every common method in a Java class.

Comment: Why don't you use service ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMethodCall(ModelMap modelMap ){
    return postMethodCall();
}
```